# Function with time limit

Tags: lua

I have a function in Lua that tries to make an ssh and/or telnet connection but some ips take forever.
I would like some way to return false after a timeout if it takes too long, is this possible in lua?

I researched about hook, but I didn't understand very well.

So I would like to give a kill returning false if it takes x minutes

Comment: `I have a function in Lua that tries to make an ssh and/or telnet connection` - How do you invoke ssh from Lua?

Comment: This depends on how you invoke the SSH connection. Please add more detail to your question.